# ASUS laptop won't reboot on Windows 7/Ubuntu dual boot after running Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I shrunk my HDD and installed Ubuntu 12.04. Everything worked great, but if I reboot and run Windows and reboot, all I get is the "ASUS" screen and a cursor int the top left corner for a few seconds before it repeats the cycle. As long as I don't ever boot Windows, I don't have this problem. Within Ubuntu I can access all of my documents, etc. But there are certain things that I *have* to do in Windows.

So far, what I've been doing is just reinstalling Ubuntu whenever I absolutely have to run Windows, but it's getting annoying. At least the install is fast and easy, but I'd like to be able to modify a few things and have them stick.

Comment: just search around you can find bunches of related topics here. To be simple, what you need to do is to re-install grub/grub2, a link for your reference: http://goo.gl/O3elh

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Plus OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and appears to have lost interest or the problem went away on its own. VTC as `not reproducible`.